# Google Sheets: How can I extract partial text from a string based on a column of different options?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, extract

**Goal:** I have a bunch of keywords I'd like to categorise automatically based on topic parameters I set. Categories that match must be in the same column so the keyword data can be filtered.

e.g. If I have "Puppies" as a first topic, it shouldn't appear as a secondary or third topic otherwise the data cannot be filtered as needed.

**Example Data:** https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TWYepApOtWDlwoTP8zkaflD7AoxD_LZ4PxssSpFlrWQ/edit?usp=sharing

**Video:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/11T5hhyestKRY4GpuwC7RF6tx-xQudNok/view?usp=sharing

**Parameters Tab:** I will add words in columns D-F that change based on the keyword data set and there will often be hundreds, if not thousands, of options for larger data sets.

**Categories Tab:** I'd like to have a formula or script that goes down the columns D-F in Parameters and fills in a corresponding value (in Categories! columns D-F respectively) based on partial match with column B or C (makes no difference to me if there's a delimiter like a space or not. Final data sheet should only have one of these columns though).

**Things I've Tried:**
I've tried a bunch of things. Nested IF formula with regexmatch works but seems clunky.

e.g. this formula in Categories! column D

=IF(REGEXMATCH($B2,LOWER(Parameters!$D$3)),Parameters!$D$3,IF(REGEXMATCH($B2,LOWER(Parameters!$D$4)),Parameters!$D$4,""))

I nested more statements changing out to the next cell in Parameters!D column (as in , manually adding $D$5, $D$6 etc) but this seems inefficient for a list thousands of words long. e.g. third topic will get very long once all dog breed types are added.

Any tips?

**Functionality I haven't worked out:**
if a string in Categories B or C contains more than one topic in the parameters I set out, is there a way I can have the first 2 to show instead of just the first one?

e.g. Cell A14 in Categories, how can I get a formula/automation to add both "Akita" & "German Shepherd" into the third topic? Concatenation with a CHAR(10) to add to new line is ideal format here. There will be other keywords that won't have both in there in which case these values will just show up individually.

Since this data set has a bunch of mixed breeds and all breeds are added as a third topic, it would be great to differentiate interest in mixes vs pure breeds without confusion.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated! Also, I'm open to variations in layout and functionality of the spreadsheet in case you have a more creative solution. I just care about efficiently automating a tedious task!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using custom function:

**To create custom function:**

1.Create or open a spreadsheet in Google Sheets.

2.Select the menu item Tools > Script editor.

3.Delete any code in the script editor and copy and paste the code below into the script editor.

4.At the top, click Save save.

**To use custom function:**

1.Click the cell where you want to use the function.

2.Type an equals sign (=) followed by the function name and any input value — for example, =DOUBLE(A1) — and press Enter.

3.The cell will momentarily display Loading..., then return the result.

**Code:**

```
function matchTopic(p, str) {
  var params = p.flat(); //Convert 2d array into 1d
  var buildRegex = params.map(i => '(' + i + ')').join('|'); //convert array into series of capturing groups. Example (Dog)|(Puppies)
  var regex = new RegExp(buildRegex,"gi");
  var results = str.match(regex);
  if(results){
    // The for loops below will convert the first character of each word to Uppercase
    for(var i = 0 ; i < results.length ; i++){
        var words = results[i].split(" ");
        for (let j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
          words[j] = words[j][0].toUpperCase() + words[j].substr(1);
        }
        results[i] = words.join(" ");
    }       
    return results.join(","); //return with comma separator
  }else{
    return ""; //return blank if result is null
  }
}
```

**Example Usage:**

**Parameters:**

[image]

**First Topic:**

[image]

**Second Topic:**

[image]

**Third Topic:**

[image]

### Reference:

- [Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Answer (score 0):

I've added a new sheet ("Erik Help") with separate formulas (highlighted in green currently) for each of your keyword columns. They are each essentially the same except for specific column references, so I'll include only the "First Topic" formula here:

`=ArrayFormula({"First Topic";IF(A2:A="",,IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(B2:B&C2:C),JOIN("|",LOWER(FILTER(Parameters!D3:D,Parameters!D3:D<>""))))) & IFERROR(CHAR(10)&REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(LOWER(B2:B&C2:C),IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(B2:B&C2:C),JOIN("|",LOWER(FILTER(Parameters!D3:D,Parameters!D3:D<>""))))),""),JOIN("|",LOWER(FILTER(Parameters!D3:D,Parameters!D3:D<>""))))))})`

This formula first creates the header (which can be changed within the formula itself as you like).

The opening `IF` condition leaves any row in the results column blank if the corresponding cell in Column A of that row is also blank.

`JOIN` is used to form a concatenated string of all keywords separated by the pipe symbol, which `REGEXEXTRACT` interprets as `OR`.

`IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(B2:B&C2:C),JOIN("|",LOWER(FILTER(Parameters!D3:D,Parameters!D3:D<>"")))))` will attempt to extract any of the keywords from each concatenated string in Columns B and C. If none is found, `IFERROR` will return null.

Then a second-round attempt is made:

`& IFERROR(CHAR(10)&REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(LOWER(B2:B&C2:C),IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(B2:B&C2:C),JOIN("|",LOWER(FILTER(Parameters!D3:D,Parameters!D3:D<>""))))),""),JOIN("|",LOWER(FILTER(Parameters!D3:D,Parameters!D3:D<>"")))))`

Only this time, `REGEXREPLACE` is used to replace the results of the first round with null, thus eliminating them from being found in round two. This will cause any *second* listing from the `JOIN` clause to be found, if one exists. Otherwise, `IFERROR` again returns null for round two.

`CHAR(10)` is the new-line character.

I've written each of the three formulas to return up to two results for *each* keyword column. If that is not your intention for "First Topic" and "Second Topic" (i.e., if you only wanted a maximum of one result for each of those columns), just select and delete the entire round-two portion of the formula shown above from the formula in each of those columns.